# Executing unix shell commands using PHP

Tags: php, shell, unix

A text box will be used to capture the command. I've been told that I have to use the `exec()` function to execute UNIX shell commands.

Something like this, user types ls in the text box. The `exec()` function will execute the UNIX command and the command will be displayed on the web page.

What I want to know how will I get the output of the shell command and display in the web browser using PHP.

I don't know where to start since I'm very new to PHP.

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: You're probably going to hear this a lot, and it may not even be relevant, but hoo boy does this sound dangerous.

Comment: Hopefully he just wants to write a web-based shell for himself. But in that case better use [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/)

Comment: You obviusly want this for a personal project, but as stated you should understand that someone can format your partitions from 1 simple command

Comment: Even though this is dangerous, I don't think this should be downvoted because of that alone. It is better to educate then to scare!

Comment: I, for one, prefer educating *through* scaring.

Comment: @gnur, it was my downvote and I have revoked it now, you have a perfectly valid point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could start looking at the php manual:

[System program execution](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php)

But like sdleihssirhc mentioned, watchout this IS very dangerous and you should **NOT** allow everything to be executed!
If you still want to do it, to get the output of the shell, just use

[exec](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
The output of the shell will be passed in the second parameter.

E.g.:

```
exec('ls -la', $outputArray);
print_r($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 13):

`exec`?

`system`?

`shell_exec`?

`passthru`?

Backticks?

*Pfah!*

*Real* developers use [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)!  It has the major and distinct advantage of giving you three PHP streams to feed data into the process, and read *both* `stdout` and `stderr`.  This is something that the other process execution functions simply don't do well.

It comes at the small cost of some boilerplate code, so it's a bit more verbose.  I consider the trade-off to be excellent.

Oh, **and running arbitrary commands from your users is perhaps one of the greatest security risks that you could ever conceive of,** but I kind of assume you know this by now.

Answer (score 5):

Use `$output = system($command);`

See http://php.net/system and don't forget to read the warnings about security. If you let a user pass any data to `system()` (or `exec()` etc.) it's almost as if they had a shell on your server. The same applies if you don't sanitize arguments passed to programs executed through these functions properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try `$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');`

doc [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec)

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is one line you can just `echo` the return value of `exec`.

Like so:

`echo exec('ls');`

But it only displays the first line.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec(escapeshellarg($userSuppliedInput), $output);

echo $output;
```

Comment: `escapeshellarg` should be used to prevent shell attacks, this guy seem's to want them, this would not work the same way with `escapeshellarg` in there.

Comment: Meh, you could say it's a habit :P

Comment: @Peeter: In this case you must be used `escapeshellcmd()` instead of `escapeshellarg()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the backticks for this purpose. Like:

```
$output = `command-executable -switches`
```

In addition, some applications echo their output to the STD_ERR stream so you might not see output. On linux, you can redirect the error input to the 'normal' input by appending `2>&1` to the command string.

Comment: what if i want to execute the output of one command as an input to another. $op=exec('cd /root/Envs/ate/bin; pwd;source ./activate; python box_upgrade.py',$output,$status); Each of the command requires the previous command to be executed.