# CakePHP CLI Commandline execution

Tags: cakephp, command-line-interface

I want to execute a Commandline by using the CakePHP-CLI. I want to build a function that executes another application using the command-Line. I cant find anything useful in the Documentation.
Did someone else got that issue before?

Thanks alot.

**EDIT**

I have created a CLI-Class called Database where already are some database synchronising functions in there. Now I want to use an external Tool called "Liquibase".
Which is executed using a Commandline. Like

```
java -jar liquibase.jar -parameter1 -parameter2
```

The problem is have no idea how to execute such a command-line out of CakePHP-CLI.

I tried this

```
 $this->runCommand("echo 'test'");
```

but the output isn't displayed.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I guess you built a shell then? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runCommand` is only intended for running (cake) shell / task methods, [see](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#Shell::runCommand). If want to execute external commands use something like `exec`, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631600/executing-unix-shell-commands-using-php).