# How to create a web based console that interacts with the command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, docker, lxc

There are a few websites that allow you to code in a online editor, and then it compiles on a server and displays the output.

I am guessing they are using docker and/or lxc to create a safe environment and isolate it for each session.

How do they display exactly what the terminal is displaying like e.g. the compile errors or the running output?

Comment: A command line compiler will output to stdout/err ...

Comment: @AlexK.ok, so how do you redirect or save that output to display on a webpage?

Comment: Depends on your language, E.g. proc_open in PHP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631600/executing-unix-shell-commands-using-php/5631687#5631687