# how can execute specific command in PHP

Tags: php

let's say I have

```
user@123:~/project/tools$ ./res.sh ../example/data/data.sql
```

how can do that in php because I don't want to do that manually when I run my code

Comment: take a look [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or  [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing unix shell commands using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631600/executing-unix-shell-commands-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file you add the following line:

```
exec("/home/123/project/tools/res.sh ../example/data/data.sql");
```